# How to simulate the left-hand rule?

Tags: c++, physics

[image]

I use a struct to represent the direction like this:

```
struct POINT{
double x;
double y;
double z; 
}
```

Given the `B(Bx,By,Bz)` and `I(Ix,Iy,Iz)`. How to determine the F?

Comment: This has more to do with electricity than programming. If you know the formula then it's not hard to devise an algorithm in any programming language for it.

Comment: Code the cross product of two vectors.

Comment: That's interesting: In Germany we use a *right-hand* rule for this, with the roles of index finger and middle finger reversed.

Comment: @celtschk Opposite in the northern hemisphere, Coriolis Effect. (Just kidding)

Comment: @celtschk it's a matter of definition - pos to neg or the other way around. see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWg3B3LAVI0&spfreload=10).

Comment: @MordechayS: Actually, it's not. Thanks to the **exchange of finger roles,** both rules refer to the *same* definition of signs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is actually what is the algorithm for a [vector cross-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).

```
POINT F;
F.x = (B.y * I.z) - (B.z * I.y);
F.y = (B.z * I.x) - (B.x * I.z);
F.z = (B.x * I.y) - (B.y * I.x);
```

Comment: Thank you. And how to calculate the angle between the I(x,y,z) and B(x,y,z) when the I and B is not orthogonal? Because I want to get the value of the F, according to F=BILSin(B,I).